# Getting HTTP 406 in Android Webservice Call

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting 406 when i invoke the rest web service via android application.Can  any one suggest me what is the error in this  code and why i am getting this error ??

### Rest Web service

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mainreservationChartPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ModelMap getMRChartDataPOST(@ModelAttribute ("ReservationSummaryRQDTO") ReservationSummaryRQDTO search){

        ReservationSummaryDTO returnDataDTO = new ReservationSummaryDTO();

        MainReservationChartWSImpl wsImpl = MRWSUtil.getInstance().getWS_ServicePort();

        search.setHotelCode("BBH");
        search.setReportDate(toXmlDateGMT(new Date()));

        returnDataDTO = wsImpl.getReservationSummary(search);

        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        model.put("reservations", returnDataDTO);

        return model;

    }
```

---

Android Code

```
public static String POST(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameter)
            throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application*/*");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameter, "utf-8"));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }



@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hotelCode","BBH"));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reportDate","10-MAY-2013"));


     //String response=hcc.executeHttpPost("http://10.2.241.137/ua_dat/rnd/senddata.php", nameValuePairs);
         try { 
            String response=HttpCustomClient.POST("http://10.2.241.33/MRChartService/mainreservationChart.html", nameValuePairs);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error", e.getMessage().toString()); 
        }




    }
```

Any one can suggest how to resolve this ..? any error in this code because i'm getting an 406 error ...

Answer (score 4):

406 means that the type of data being requested in the accept header of the request and the type returned by the server don't match.  Either change your accepted type or change your return mime type.

Comment: i change the accept header as  httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); and add the same to the method  @RequestMapping(value="/mainreservationChartPost", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Content-Type=application/json") but still the issue is there

Answer (score 0):

That error is not acceptable.

Literally.

[Here is some documentation on it](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html):

It generally means that the service sent stuff back to you in an unrecognizable format. It could be the wrong kind of data, or the headers could just be screwed up.  You should try to use a packet sniffer like WireShark to see what is getting sent back.  Also, it could be that  you just need to specify the content type.

If you are doing webservice calls, and you've never used a packet sniffer, it would be a great idea to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

406 is returned by the server when it can't respond based on accepting the request headers (ie they have an Accept header which states they only want XML). Check the Accept header in response from the server and send the data appropriately.

Comment: headers="Content-Type=application/json this is the header i accepting and i changed the httpost.setHeader("Content-type",
                    "application/json"); but no reuslt